# remix run useFetcher to post an array and then get the array in the action

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I am using remix run.
I am using the useFetcher hook to submit an array. However when I receive it in the action of the route it is being submitted to, it has changed from an array into a string.
I would like to keep it as an array, or at least JSON.

```
// FUNCTION TO SEND SELECTED_IDS ARRAY TO API ROUTE
const fetcher = useFetcher();
const deleteSelected = () => {
  const selected_ids = [1,2,3,4]; 
  fetcher.submit({ids: selected_ids}, { method: "post", action: "/api/delete" });
}    

// api/delete action
export async function action({ request }) {
  let formData = await request.formData();
  let ids = formData.get("ids");
  console.log(ids); // outputs 1,2,3,4 expected array or JSON [1,2,3,4]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `formData.getAll("ids")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll

Comment: thanks for your response. That still seems to produce a string, but this time it includes the brackets for the array!. I think the problem is that the form correctly POSTs with multipart/form-data headers - and therefore should send the array as a string. It would then be for the backend to decipher the data and in this case convert it into array. I think my confusion has arisen, because in the past I have POST arrays using json header and the backend automatically received them as arrays.

Comment: I think this discussion would be usefull @jon --> https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/10324#discussioncomment-5725056